# Email verification laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Recently I start to use laravel 7 to write an e-com website, my question is how can i add email verification

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/verification : already read

```
    Auth::routes(['register'=>false]);

Route::get('user/login','FrontendController@login')->name('login.form');
Route::post('user/login','FrontendController@loginSubmit')->name('login.submit');
Route::get('user/logout','FrontendController@logout')->name('user.logout');

Route::get('user/register','FrontendController@register')->name('register.form');
Route::post('user/register','FrontendController@registerSubmit')->name('register.submit');
// Reset password
Route::post('password-reset', 'FrontendController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset'); 
// Socialite 
Route::get('login/{provider}/', 'Auth\LoginController@redirect')->name('login.redirect');
Route::get('login/{provider}/callback/', 'Auth\LoginController@Callback')->name('login.callback');

Route::get('/','FrontendController@home')->name('home');

// Frontend Routes
Route::get('/home', 'FrontendController@index');
Route::get('/about-us','FrontendController@aboutUs')->name('about-us');
Route::get('/contact','FrontendController@contact')->name('contact');
Route::post('/contact/message','MessageController@store')->name('contact.store');
Route::get('product-detail/{slug}','FrontendController@productDetail')->name('product-detail');
Route::post('/product/search','FrontendController@productSearch')->name('product.search');
Route::get('/product-cat/{slug}','FrontendController@productCat')->name('product-cat');
Route::get('/product-sub-cat/{slug}/{sub_slug}','FrontendController@productSubCat')->name('product-sub-cat');
Route::get('/product-brand/{slug}','FrontendController@productBrand')->name('product-brand');
```

user table

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->string('photo')->nullable();
            $table->enum('role',['admin','user'])->default('user');
            $table->string('provider')->nullable();
            $table->string('provider_id')->nullable();
            $table->enum('status',['active','inactive'])->default('active');
            $table->rememberToken()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

EventServiceProvider

```
@var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
    ];
```

App\User implements Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','role','photo','status','provider','provider_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order');
    }
}
```

and this is my email verification controller

```
use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
```

thanks for your help

Comment: You can see in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/verification

Comment: With all due respect, you won't be able to build an ecommerce website, if your first port of call is to come here and ask for help. Your question could be answered if you took two minutes to read the documentation. I'd advise you to learn Laravel by following some tutorials online, before starting a project when you have no idea how Laravel works. Also, you've shown us your routes, but nothing else...

Comment: composer require laravel/ui already instaled bro and my project works i have a problem just with the middleware (verify your email) login-home thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a field in your database called `verification_token` and generate a unique string during registration and send the code to the user's email with a link format, for example,

http://localhost:8000/verify-email-address?token=123456&email=user@example.com

if then email matches with the token in database then the user `verification_token` will became blank after hitting the URL and user can be able to login

Comment: i didn't understand how can i do this ?

Comment: Just create a migration to add a field in your users table call 'verification_token' and create a add unique string and insert along with user details during registration and send that string as link to the user's registered email address. Add a route for the verification link and and check where the token in link matches with the users email in database. if matched then remove the verification string from database. During the login place a check whether the verification_token empty field for the given user.

Comment: Please mark this answer as right and flag the comment as helpful, if you're satisfied with the answer